# Windows alert triggered by a linux service?

Tags: linux, windows, web-services

We are running a Linux service that creates error events from time to time. Now we would like to notify Windows users about these events, either with a pop-up window, or better with a message on a Tray Icon.

Comment: No body can help you with their answers. I guess..

Comment: Guys, I share your non-appreciation for Windows. We have to deal with no-so-linux-sophisticated-end-users who unfortunately are running Windows, but still need to know about important security events in real-time. What is your problem?

Comment: @fraber: It's got nothing to do with Windows or Linux. It's that you haven't asked a sensible question. You have something that runs on Linux and can create error reports. Great. You want to notify Windows users of those errors. Great. What, **specifically**, is the issue? Or is the issue: "how do I do this?"

Comment: @Nik: At least w33mhz apparently understood the issue pretty well (see below). We are looking for a "middleware" or a "notification service" that will produce these TrayIcon warnings on the Windows machines. Maybe I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a third party messaging service you could write a client app to check the message queue.

http://www.rabbitmq.com/